# Show $1+1/p+1/p^2+...=\exp(1/p+O(1/p^2))$

Tags: number-theory, analysis

In [this note](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/11/13/254a-announcement-analytic-prime-number-theory/), T.Tao proved Thm 2 while invoking $$1+\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^2}+\dots=\exp(\frac{1}{p}+O(\frac{1}{p^2})).$$

Why does this hold?

Comment: Use $\ln(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $e^h=1+h+O(h^2)$ or similarly $1+x=e^{x+O(x^2)}$. Or if you want it more strictly
$$
1+h+h^2+h^3+...=\frac1{1-h}=e^{h+h^2/2+h^3/3+...}=e^{h+O(h^2)}.
$$